# Using Tabs,Wifi and Gps

Tags: android, gps, tabwidget, android-wifi

Am Generating 3 tabs dynamically under 1st tab am generating a toggle button using which i can switch off and on both GPS and WIFI
I have coded java files for GPS and WIFI. I have checked again and again line by line but couldn't find any bug.
I have run in the emulator and android "Sony Arc mobile also."Installation also goes well and problem arises when i try to launch.
The application is showing the message "**The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again**" I have referred almost{*all*} all the queries in stack overflow and couldn't get any possible answer for my scenario..
I tried removing the GPS and WIFI files in the application and replacing *Toggle Button* with *TextView* then its working fine.
  Am including my code please verify it and help me out buddies.

> **Main.java**
>
> > package project.sow;
> >     import android.app.TabActivity;
> >     import android.content.Intent;
> >     import android.content.res.Resources;
> >     import android.os.Bundle;
> >     import android.widget.TabHost;
> >     public class Main extends TabActivity {
> >         private TabHost tabHost;
> >         @Override
> >         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> >             try{
> >             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> >             setContentView(R.layout.main);
> >             Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
> >             tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); //The activity TabHost
> >             TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
> >                      // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
> >             spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Start").setIndicator("Start",
> >                               res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sample));
> >             spec.setContent(new Intent(this,Start.class));
> >             tabHost.addTab(spec);
> >             spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info").setIndicator("Info",   res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sample));
> >             spec.setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, Info.class));
> >             tabHost.addTab(spec);

```
   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Update").setIndicator("Update",   res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sample));             
    spec.setContent(new Intent(this, Update.class));  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);  

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);  
}catch(Exception e)  
{
    android.util.Log.i("PREFS",e.getMessage());  
} } }
```

> **Start.java**
>
> > package project.sow;
> >     import android.app.Activity;
> >     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
> >     import android.content.Context;
> >     import android.content.IntentFilter;
> >     import android.location.LocationListener;
> >     import android.location.LocationManager;
> >     import android.location.LocationProvider;
> >     import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
> >     import android.os.Bundle;
> >     import android.widget.TextView;
> >     import android.widget.Toast;
> >     import android.widget.ToggleButton;
> >     public class Start extends Activity {
> >         public WifiManager wifi;
> >         boolean status;
> >         Context context;
> >         public TextView textStatus;
> >         public LocationManager locationManager;
> >         public LocationListener locationListener;
> >         public BroadcastReceiver receiver;
> >         public LocationProvider locationProvider;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        try{   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);           
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);  
        textview.setText("Toggle to On r Off the Application");  
        setContentView(textview);  
        ToggleButton btnonoff = new ToggleButton(this);  
        setContentView(btnonoff);  
        if(btnonoff.isChecked()){  
           status=true;  
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);  
            try{  
            // Setup WiFi  
            wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);  
            locationManager = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
            if (receiver == null)  
                receiver = new WiFiFilter(this);                
            registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(  
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));  
            if (locationListener ==null ){locationListener=new gpsLocation(this);} 
            }  
            catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(context, WIFI_SERVICE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}  
       }   
       else if(!btnonoff.isChecked()) {  
          status=false;    
           if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){  
           wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);  
           locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);  
           }  
            }               
        }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  
            android.util.Log.i("PREFS",e.getMessage());  
        }  
}     }
```

> **WifiFilter.java**
>
> > package project.sow;
> >     import java.util.List;
> >     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
> >     import android.content.Context;
> >     import android.content.Intent;
> >     import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
> >     import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
> >     import android.util.Log;
> >     import android.widget.Toast;
> >     public class WiFiFilter extends BroadcastReceiver {
> >       private static final String TAG = "WiFiFilter";
> >       Start start;
> >         public WiFiFilter(Start start) {
> >         super();
> >         this.start=start;
> >       }
> >       //Preparing for Hidden SSID and saving the wifi config for later use
> >             @Override
> >       public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
> >         List results = start.wifi.getScanResults();
> >         List results2 = null;
> >         ScanResult filter = null;
> >         //filtering SSID
> >         for(ScanResult filterresult : results ){
> >            if(filterresult.SSID=="VOLSBB")
> >            {
> >                results2 = results;}
> >             }
> >          //Checking the signal Level
> >           for (ScanResult result : results2) {
> >           if (filter == null
> >               || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(filter.level, result.level) < 0)
> >             filter = result;
> >           try{
> >           WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK.equals(filter);
> >           }
> >           catch(Exception e){String res="Exception:No network";Toast.makeText(start, res,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();};
> >         }
> >         String message = String.format("Connected to S0W");
> >         if(filter.SSID != null){
> >         //Toast.makeText(start, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> >         Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);
> >       }
> >        }  }

**gpsLocation.java**

> package project.sow;
>   import project.sow.CustomWebView;
>   import android.location.Criteria;
>   import android.location.GpsStatus;
>   import android.location.Location;
>   import android.location.LocationListener;
>   import android.location.LocationManager;
>   import android.os.Bundle;
>   import project.sow.Start;
>   public class gpsLocation implements LocationListener{
>       Start sowWifigps;
>       public Location currentBestLocation;
>       public Location location;
>       GpsStatus status;
>       CustomWebView webviewgps;
>       double a;
>       double b;
>       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
>       private String bestProvider;
>       //public LocationManager locationManager;
>           public String provider1;
>       public gpsLocation(Start sowWifigps) {
>           super();
>           this.sowWifigps=sowWifigps;
>           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>           Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
>           //bestProvider = sowWifigps.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
>           try{
>           if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER==null){
>               provider1 = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
>               }
>               else {provider1=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;}
>           }catch( Exception e){ provider1=sowWifigps.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);}
>       }
>    @Override
>    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>        sowWifigps.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider1, 12000, 200, sowWifigps.locationListener);
>    }
>    @Override
>    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>        //provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
>        currentBestLocation=sowWifigps.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider1);
>        a=currentBestLocation.getLatitude();
>           b=currentBestLocation.getLongitude();
>           webviewgps.loadUrl("http://localhost/mobile/default_mobile.php?lat="+a+"&long="+b); //change to site name
>    }
>    @Override
>    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       sowWifigps.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider1, 12000, 200, sowWifigps.locationListener);
>       a=currentBestLocation.getLatitude();
>       b=currentBestLocation.getLongitude();
>       webviewgps.loadUrl("http://localhost/mobile/default_mobile.php?lat="+a+"&long="+b); //change to site name
>    }
>    @Override
>    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>               sowWifigps.locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
>    }
>   }

**Am presenting here second Tab and other resembles this one.So am omitting it.**

**Info.java**

> package project.sow;
>   import android.app.Activity;
>   import android.os.Bundle;
>   public class Info extends Activity {
>        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           }
>        @Override
>           protected void onResume() {
>               CustomWebView webView = new CustomWebView(this);
>               webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/?s=Info");
>               setContentView(webView);
>               super.onResume();
>           }  }

> > **CustomWebView.java**    
> >     package project.sow;
> >     import android.app.ProgressDialog;
> >     import android.content.Context;
> >     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
> >     import android.view.View;
> >     import android.webkit.WebView;
> >     import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
> >     public class CustomWebView  extends WebView {
> >         private ProgressDialog pgBar = null;
> >         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
> >         private Context ctx;
> >         public CustomWebView(Context context) {
> >             super(context);
> >             this.clearCache(true);
> >             this.clearFormData();
> >             this.clearHistory();
> >             this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
> >             this.getSettings().setUserAgentString(null);
> >             this.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
> >             this.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebView.CustomWebViewClient());
> >             this.pgBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
> >             this.pgBar.setMessage("Loading...");
> >             ctx = context;
> >         }
> >         private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
> >             @Override
> >             public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)   {
> >                 super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
> >                 if (!CustomWebView.this.pgBar.isShowing()) {
> >                     CustomWebView.this.pgBar.show();
> >                 }
> >             }
> >             @Override
> >             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
> >                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
> >                 if (CustomWebView.this.pgBar.isShowing()) {
> >                     CustomWebView.this.pgBar.dismiss();
> >                 }
> >             }
> >             @Override
> >             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
> >                 try{
> >                     view.loadUrl(url);
> >                 }catch(Exception ex){
> >                 }
> >                 return true;
> >             }  }  }

main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com  /apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:background="#cabfa9">  
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"  
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"   android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:background="#1b3b5b" ></TabWidget>  
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:background="#cabfa9">           
    </FrameLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>  
</TabHost>
```

**style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="tabText" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">        
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10dip</item>        
    </style>    

</resources>
```

`

**ic_sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon2" />
</selector>
```

> I have added the following permissions  in the manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Answer (score 0):

**WI-FI and GPS are to be called in the main threads rather than in child threads..**
So in the main.java,

```
try{  
   // Setup WiFi  
   wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);  
   locationManager = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
   if (receiver == null)  
       receiver = new WiFiFilter(this);                
   registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(  
                  WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));  
   if (locationListener ==null ){
       locationListener=new gpsLocation(this);
       } 
   }  
   catch(Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(context, WIFI_SERVICE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }  
}
```

**Are to be placed which are formerly called initialized in the start.java**

> By doing this the processes are not killed which are important and stops the application from crashing.